RegionFunction fails on a quite simply plot
The green surface and the red curves are plotted on the same RegionFunction -> (-1 < #1 < 1 && -1 < #2 < 1 && -1 < #3 < 1 &) but as can be seen there are several points of red curves that are outside that region, one of them too much. That point was deleted in the next image.
Why RegionFunction fails to get rid of the point {1.06263, -0.51858, 1.01353}?
How to avoid this?
I might increase working precision and use 1/10 and 3/10 instead of 0.1 and 0.3 in the code, but that slows down plotting.
Update: Using exact numbers and WorkingPrecision -> 100 did not help so I consider it as a bug. Anyway, any ideas for workaround?
fi=4.7 is the bad curve.
Show[ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationMatrix[0.3, {0, 1, 2}] . {x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> (-1 < #1 < 1 && -1 < #2 < 1 && -1 < #3 < 1 &), 
  PlotStyle -> Green], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Table[RotationMatrix[fi, 
      RotationMatrix[0.3, {0, 1, 2}] . {0, 0, 1}] . 
     RotationMatrix[0.3, {0, 1, 2}] . {t, t, 2 t^2}, {fi, {0.1, 
      4.7}}] // Evaluate, {t, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> (-1 < #1 < 1 && -1 < #2 < 1 && -1 < #3 < 1 &), 
  PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False], ViewPoint -> Top, ImageSize -> 300]

SortBy[Cases[%, {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} /; z > 1, All], 
  Part[3]] // Last
DeleteCases[%%, %, All]




PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 4

@cvgmt It is just a coincidence that it solves this particular example. I have a more complicated example where I used PlotPoints -> 100 and WorkingPrecision -> 100 and it did no help. There is a bug in RegionFunction that it does not filter points properly.

@cvgmt Second point is that I am fine with default number of plot points I do not need to increase it since it does not improve quality just slows down plotting.

Please post a MWE that PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 4 does not work.

@cvgmt Also it does not work even with PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 4. Try with  {fi, {0.1, 0.9, 4.7}}. It solves curve fi=4.7 but not curve fi=0.9.

The PlotPoints->100 work for the lines.  The green surface is wrong, there are only two missing corners instead of three.  ParametricPlot3D[  RotationMatrix[0.3, {0, 1, 2}] . {x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -1.1,    1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1},   RegionFunction -> (-1 <= #1 <= 1 && -1 <= #2 <= 1 && -1 <= #3 <=        1 &), PlotStyle -> Green]

Too long for comment, have to seperate to two comments. ParametricPlot3D[  RotationMatrix[0.3, {0, 1, 2}] . {x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -1.1,    1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},   PlotStyle -> Green]

@cvgmt Number of plot points is irrelevant for the question. As I wrote in previous comment it is just a coincidence that the lines are corrected for some specific number of plot points. Even if it was, say, PlotPoints->1 RegionFunction should filter the points properly in any case.... and here we have the simplest possible definition of region - it is just comparing of coordinates, no calculation needed.

Please test PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 0,  though you set PlotPoints small, but mathematica still use MaxRecursion to add extra points.

@cvgmt What are you trying to say with your example? With PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 0 the plot is correct, there is no point outside the region.
